# Dynamically created component added at the end of the page instead of immediate bottom

Tags: angular, angular-material, hierarchical-data

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material2-3level-hierarchy)

I'm trying to achieve hierarchical component view and for that i have created 3 level hierarchy. when user click on any level, its corresponding child level should be open.

I have used ComponentFactoryResolver and created the component run time as I want that every instance of child is different.

Everything is working fine, the only problem I have is that, newly created component is adding at the bottom of the page. I want that newly added component should add at the bottom of the clicked row. see the problem in below image.

[image: Issue]

Feel free this edit this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material2-3level-hierarchy)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the new component is getting added to the end of the template because `tRef` is always undefined. This causes the following block to always be called:

```
if (!this.tRef) {
     this.setTemplate.emit(this);
}
```

And the following always evaluates to false:

```
if (this.tRef && this.row)
```

I added the template reference that was commented and the hirechy appears to be working as expected:

```
<mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;" class="element-row" 
       [cdkDetailRow]="row"
       (toggleChange)="onToggleChange($event,row)" 
       (setTemplate)="setTemplate($event,row)"
       [cdkDetailRowTpl]="tpl">
</mat-row>
```

As far as the row detail getting updated, this is because `set currentPosition` is getting called since it is detecting a change in the `level2Pos` field. There might be better ways, but a quick solution with the way you have it set up is to wrap the `set` method logic so position is only set the first time:

```
set currentPosition(val: number) {
    if(!this.l2Pos) {
      this.dataSource2.data = data2.filter(x => x.position === val);
      this.dataSource2.paginator = this.paginator2;
      this.dataSource2.sort = this.sort;
      this.l2Pos = val;
    }
}
```

---

Alternatively, you could exploit Angular's change detection by wrapping the position in an object and always passing the same reference.

Create a wrapper object:

```
export interface PositionContext {
  position: number;
}
```

Ensure the same reference is always passed to the template:

```
(table-basic-example.ts)
levelTwoPositionContext: PositionContext = {position: null};
```

.

```
(table-basic-example.html)
<ng-template #tpl let-element let-row="row">
    <level2 [currentPosition]="levelTwoPositionContext"></level2>
</ng-template>
```

Update wrapped position:

```
(table-basic-example.ts)
this.levelTwoPositionContext.position = row.position;
```

No extra logic needed in set:

```
@Input()
  set currentPosition(val: PositionContext) {
      this.dataSource2.data = data2.filter(x => x.position === val.position);
      this.dataSource2.paginator = this.paginator2;
      this.dataSource2.sort = this.sort;
  }
```

Comment: Where you have added? Also if I go with your suggestion and expand two row, it has a same child which is not expected.

Comment: ' [cdkDetailRowTpl]="tpl" ' is what I added to mat-row in your stackBlitz example.

Comment: If we do that, it lead to same instance in all child. For instance. if you open first row , child will show record related to 1 but as you open second row, first row also shows records from second's child.

Comment: I see that now, added a quick workaround, hope it helps.

Comment: It works, thanks. Also I cannot see any difference in your alternate solution apart from just wrapping postion in object, have I missed anything?

Comment: I'm happy it works! When you pass the same object reference, Angular's change detection does not fire and the set method is never called. Wrapping the position with an object allows us to do this. You might not need it in your situation but it is something to be aware of.

Comment: can you please see this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58938957/set-overlay-dark-background-other-than-current-row-in-mat-table